# How to call a function in Laravel after charge?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I would like to run a function in my controller using Laravel... 2 o more seconds after the page has been refreshed

How could I do that?

Comment: Doing something after the page has been refreshed will mean JavaScript, via an AJAX request.

Comment: You could queue a job or use after middleware but you would need to put some effort into elaborating on your question to get a thoughtful and thorough response.

Answer (score 1):

you can use js , or you can use

```
$job = (new YourEvent($coolEvent))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(2));
```

2 is the seconds you want to delay

and `$coolEvend` is the event you want to execute